# login cookie being reset to empty?

Tags: vb.net

Ok so im trying to make a program which will login to [b]my [/b]site the bot / software logs me in but then when i move to any other page in side my rpg it logs me back out i think it is because i reset the cookie which has logged me in.

So this is the code for my login button

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim logincookie As CookieContainer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim postData As String = "username=" & TextBox2.Text & "&password=" & TextBox1.Text & "&submit=Login"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.myurl.net/login.php?tid="), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "http://www.myurl.net/login.php?tid="
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage

    End Sub
```

Notice the Dim logincookie As CookieContainer at the top....

That all works perfect ( it logs me in )
I then have another button now to test to see if i can submit a basic html form

and here is that button code

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://myurl.net/signature.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.CookieContainer = logincookie
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim theusercp As String = reader.ReadToEnd

        RichTextBox2.Text = theusercp
    End Sub
```

Notice i do not declare the Dim logincookie As CookieContainer at the top of this one maybe that is were im going wrong ?
After i click the second button and this bottom bit of code is active it logs me out... i think its me resetting the login cookie ? Or maybe not setting it right ??

Im trying to make it so users can login to my site via this exe and update there sig etc...

P.s the both buttons will submit the html back to me so i can see the logout

Comment: So, you already identified a potential fix for the issue.  Why did you not try it and see before posting?

Comment: Its not been fixed... I know nothing about vb.net i just to follow a tut.   So what do you think is wrong with the code ?